Почему может не срабатывать сигнал?
class QuikTerminal(QObject):
data_stream_candles_signal = Signal(object)
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.all_orders = None
    self.app = None
    self.positions = None
    self.client_code = None
    self.all_assets = None
    self.current_bal = None
    self.portfolio = None
    self.accounts = None
    self.message = None
    self.data = None
    self.data_candles = {}

    self.qp_provider = None  # Экземпляр QuikPy
    self.lock = threading.Lock()  # Для потокобезопасности
    self.logger = logging.getLogger('QuikPy.Stream')


def quik_on(self):
    if self.qp_provider is None:
        self.qp_provider = QuikPy()
        self.message = f'Подключено к QUIK: {self.qp_provider.host}'
    return self.message

def quik_off(self):
    if self.qp_provider:
        self.qp_provider.close_connection_and_thread()
        self.qp_provider = None
        self.message = 'QUIK отключен'
    return self.message


def on_new_candle(self, data):
    print('candles_thread', data)
    self.data_candles = data['data']
    print('self.data_candles', self.data_candles)
    self.data_stream_candles_signal.emit(self.data_candles)
    print('333')

def quik_base_update(self, ticker, interval, switch_load_quik):
    try:
        class_code = 'TQBR'
        sec_code = ticker
        self.qp_provider.on_new_candle = self.on_new_candle
        result = self.qp_provider.subscribe_to_candles(class_code, sec_code, int(interval))['data']  # QUIK#

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'ERROR: Ошибка загрузки данных Стрим')

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.quik_terminal = QuikTerminal()
        self.quik_terminal.data_stream_candles_signal.connect(self.handle_new_candle)

......(функции основного класса)
def load_quik_thread(self, time_limit_dict, switch_load_quik):
    try:
        self.ui.comboBox_coins.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.comboBox_time_limit_5.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.pushButton_refresh_coins.setEnabled(False)
        self.switch_sinc_enable(self.switch_load_quik)
        print(11)
        ticker = self.ui.comboBox_coins.currentText().split(' ')[0]
        interval = int(self.time_limit_dict[self.ui.comboBox_time_limit_5.currentText()])
        self.ui.tableWidget_main_data_5.clearContents()
        self.ui.tableWidget_main_data_5.setRowCount(0)
        print(22)
        stream_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.quik_terminal.quik_base_update, args=(ticker, interval, switch_load_quik,))
        print(88)
        stream_thread.start()
        stream_thread.join()  # Ждём завершения подключения
        self.statistic_update(f'Стрим {ticker} ({interval} мин.) запущен')
    except Exception as e:
        self.statistic_update(f'ERROR load_quik_thread: Проверьте подключение к терминалу')


def handle_new_candle(self, data):
    print('data', data)

Подскажите плз, уже всю голову сломал.. почему не выходит передать сигналом значения, полученные в стриминговом потоке? словарь data точно имеет нужные данные, из класска QuikTerminal все корректно выводится.. эти данные нужно передать в основной класс App, где далее обработать и засунуть в таблицу через функцию self.handle_new_candle. Но распечатывая оттуда data результат никакой, даже строки 'data' нет.. при этом ошибки не возникают.. В чем может быть дело?

А зачем вы собственно quik_base_update отдельным потоком запускаете? Вы всё-равно ждёте окончания работы этого потока там же, где его запускаете. А из-за отдельного потока могут быть какие-то проблемы.

перепроверил без потока - другие функции по прежнему нормально работают (думал так будут блокироваться), но сигнал все равно не проходит..

Так handle_new_candle срабатывает, только в data ничего нет или вообще не срабатывает? Опишите ситуацию более чётко в вопросе. А on_new_candle срабатывает?

нет.. поставил простой принт в самое начало тела функции handle_new_candle - не срабатывает вообще.. не выполняется выходит(( про то что выполняется я выше написал - это другие функции приложения..

on_new_candle  - там все правильно выводится

Я вот не очень понял, какая связь между self.data_stream_candles_signal и self.quik_terminal.data_stream_candles_signal. Это две разных сущности, так всё и задумано?

Т.к. self.data_stream_candles_signal расположение в классе QuikTerminal,  self.quik_terminal.data_stream_candles_signal - таким вот образом получается только обратиться из класса Аpp к self.data_stream_candles_signal. Если напрямую пытаться вызвать self.data_stream_candles_signal вылезает ошибка..

К сожалению не могу сейчас глубоко вникнуть в проблему, для начала советую проверить, доходит ли вообще сигнал до нужного объекта, повесив принты в начале слота. И проверить на ошибки, если доходит, ошибки в треде могут не всплывать в основном потоке, нужно повесить try: - except Exception as e: print(e), тоже может помочь понять в чём проблема

пробовал, сигнал видимо не доходит, ни ошибка в try, ни принты не срабатывают, ошибок нет.. поточность полностью убрал

@ВладСавельев вот, значит осталось понять, почему сигнал не доходит. Возможно вы вызываете его ДО того как коннектите слот. Или что-то происходит с объектом

спасибо за наводку, оказалось в еще в одном месте инициализировался class QuikTerminal, что портило очередность выполнения эмит-коннект..
